# Error while compiling JUMPCoin Wallet on Raspberry Pi (leveldb/libmemenv.a: error adding symbols:)

Tags: c++, unix, makefile, raspberry-pi, leveldb

I am trying to compile a wallet for my JUMP coins (https://github.com/Jumperbillijumper/jumpcoin).

I cloned the repo,
`cd` to `src/`
and ran `$ make -f makefile.unix`

and now I am getting this error:

```
/home/pi/jumpcoin/jumpcoin/src/leveldb/libmemenv.a: error addingsymbols: Archive has no index; run ranlib to add one
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile.unix:206: recipe for target 'jumpcoind' failed
make: *** [jumpcoind] Error 1
```

Log:

```
pi@Raspberry_Pi:~/jumpcoin/jumpcoin/src $ make -f makefile.unix
/bin/sh ../share/genbuild.sh obj/build.h
g++ -c -O2  -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-ignored-qualifiers -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wno-unused-parameter -g -DBOOST_SPIRIT_THREADSAFE -I/home/pi/jumpcoin/jumpcoin/src -I/home/pi/jumpcoin/jumpcoin/src/obj -DUSE_UPNP=0 -DUSE_IPV6=1 -I/home/pi/jumpcoin/jumpcoin/src/leveldb/include -I/home/pi/jumpcoin/jumpcoin/src/leveldb/helpers -DHAVE_BUILD_INFO -fno-stack-protector -fstack-protector-all -Wstack-protector -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -MMD -MF obj/txdb-leveldb.d -o obj/txdb-leveldb.o txdb-leveldb.cpp
g++ -O2  -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Wno-ignored-qualifiers -Wformat -Wformat-security -Wno-unused-parameter -g -DBOOST_SPIRIT_THREADSAFE -I/home/pi/jumpcoin/jumpcoin/src -I/home/pi/jumpcoin/jumpcoin/src/obj -DUSE_UPNP=0 -DUSE_IPV6=1 -I/home/pi/jumpcoin/jumpcoin/src/leveldb/include -I/home/pi/jumpcoin/jumpcoin/src/leveldb/helpers -DHAVE_BUILD_INFO -fno-stack-protector -fstack-protector-all -Wstack-protector -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -o jumpcoind obj/groestl.o obj/blake.o obj/skein.o obj/keccak.o obj/jh.o obj/alert.o obj/version.o obj/checkpoints.o obj/netbase.o obj/addrman.o obj/crypter.o obj/key.o obj/db.o obj/init.o obj/irc.o obj/keystore.o obj/miner.o obj/main.o obj/net.o obj/protocol.o obj/jumpcoinrpc.o obj/rpcdump.o obj/rpcnet.o obj/rpcmining.o obj/rpcwallet.o obj/rpcblockchain.o obj/rpcrawtransaction.o obj/script.o obj/sync.o obj/util.o obj/wallet.o obj/walletdb.o obj/noui.o obj/kernel.o obj/pbkdf2.o obj/scrypt.o obj/scrypt-arm.o obj/scrypt-x86.o obj/scrypt-x86_64.o obj/zerocoin/Accumulator.o obj/zerocoin/AccumulatorProofOfKnowledge.o obj/zerocoin/Coin.o obj/zerocoin/CoinSpend.o obj/zerocoin/Commitment.o obj/zerocoin/ParamGeneration.o obj/zerocoin/Params.o obj/zerocoin/SerialNumberSignatureOfKnowledge.o obj/zerocoin/SpendMetaData.o obj/zerocoin/ZeroTest.o obj/txdb-leveldb.o -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now   -Wl,-Bdynamic -l boost_system -l boost_filesystem -l boost_program_options -l boost_thread -l db_cxx -l ssl -l crypto -l miniupnpc -Wl,-Bdynamic -l z -l dl -l pthread /home/pi/jumpcoin/jumpcoin/src/leveldb/libleveldb.a /home/pi/jumpcoin/jumpcoin/src/leveldb/libmemenv.a
/home/pi/jumpcoin/jumpcoin/src/leveldb/libmemenv.a: error adding symbols: Archive has no index; run ranlib to add one
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile.unix:206: recipe for target 'jumpcoind' failed
make: *** [jumpcoind] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok the problem was in the src/leveldb directory (obviously)

I took the src/leveldb directory from this repo (https://github.com/sagacrypto/SagaCoin) and replaced the current one. Then everything works fine. (at least for me :P)

yeah I know it is not best practice but this one was driving me nuts :D